# Android Studio Emulator Showing Up; Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

Following online instructions, I created an app that converts kilometers to miles, and miles to kilometers. I tried to run the app, and I turned on the emulator. It showed up, but it didn't run the program. That's all I know about the problem. Any suggestions? (I really wish I had more info)

EDIT:

It says:

```
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Comment: You may not have enough available memory to handle the emulator requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your emulator is complaining because you don't have enough ram to give to the emulator.

I think you go to tools > Android > AVD manager and then select the emulator you want to use. Once selected you should be able to reduce the amount of ram to 1024m like it's asking you to do. I'm not on my pc at the moment so I hope my memory serves me well!

If that doesn't work hopefully this android document can help: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Comment: How can you "reduce the amount of ram to 1024m like it's asking you to"? I am __complete__ newbie so sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Select your device in the AVD manager and press edit. In memory options you should be able to find the RAM parameters. You can then set your RAM there. May I ask how much ram your machine has?